# How do you solve this problem in python when importing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused by `h5py` package as [known issue](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/974).

To overcome, You can do:

```
pip install numpy==1.13.0
sudo pip3 install h5py==2.8.0rc1
```